# In JDBC, when executing multiple statements - how to know for each ResultSet to which statement does it belong to?

Tags: stored-procedures, jdbc

Let's assume the following dummy example in JDBC:

```
   Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
   statement.execute("select * from X; call sp1(); select * from Y; call sp2(); select * Z");
   
   int uc = statement .getUpdateCount();
   boolean isResult = (uc == -1);

   do
   {
      if( isResult )
      {
         ResultSet rs = statement.getResultSet();

         if( rs != null )
         {
            doSomethingWithRS( rs );
         }
      }
      else
      {
         System.out.println( "update count: " + uc );
      }
   }
   while( ( isResult = statement.getMoreResults() ) || ( uc = statement.getUpdateCount() ) != -1 );
```

It is known that some Databases/Drivers allow multiple statement execution (SQL Server as an example). Notice there are 5 statements executed on the database side one-by-one. A driver emits an, unknown ahead, number of result sets. This is due the fact that stored procedures may return an  arbitrary number of result sets, depending on their internals.

Is there any way to identify, for each retrieved result set, which particular statement does it belong to?

Note, I posted another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67042636/in-jdbc-is-there-a-way-to-determine-ahead-the-number-of-resultsets-to-be-return) focusing on determining the information about stored procedure that may answer the question in the subject. Still, I hope, JDBC itself might have a way to address this issue.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in JDBC to determine which statement inside your stored procedure produced the result set. As far as JDBC is concerned, there is only one statement, the statement that you executed to execute the stored procedure. What happens inside that stored procedure is a black box to JDBC.

For the specific example you posted, the more proper way would be to execute those statements individually. The expectations of JDBC are that you execute a single statement at a time. The fact SQL Server allows you to execute multiple statements separated by semi-colons like this, is dubious from a formal JDBC perspective, but SQL Server / T-SQL handles this as a sort of 'anonymous procedure' (as if this was a stored procedure, and you executed that single stored procedure).

In theory, a specific driver could have features for this outside those defined in the JDBC specification, but given how databases and their protocols usually work, I'd be surprised if that were actually the case in reality.

Protocols are usually simple without frills, because I guess it is uncommon to have to know exactly which statement **inside** the stored procedure produced which result set<sup>1</sup>, and will therefor communicate along the lines of *"result: update count = 1"*, *"result: result set"* (followed by rows), etc.

If you really need to know which statement of the stored procedure produced which result set, then you will need to rethink what you're doing, and not use stored procedures that produce multiple results, but instead drive this from your Java application (execute them individually), or only write stored procedures with deterministic results (e.g. always producing *n* results in the exact same order), or add an extra column to the results to provide an identification explicitly.

---

<sup>**1**: Or at least, I can't really think of a practical situation where this information would be relevant (except maybe for debugging). Also, this would tightly couple the calling code to the exact and literal implementation of the stored procedure (consider what happens if the statement text changes).</sup>

Comment: I don't agree that there's anything dubious about this from a JDBC perspective. JDBC doesn't make any assumptions about the SQL string you pass to it (not even about it being SQL). As far as JDBC is concerned, whether you create anonymous statement batches (e.g. from a SQL editor!) or wrap all of this up in a stored procedure and call that is completely irrelevant.

Comment: @LukasEder The wording of the JDBC specification indicates that the expectation is that a single statement is executed, not a collection of statements. From that perspective, I consider it dubious.

Comment: Curious, I don't see any such limitation. Do you derive this reading only from the use of singular *"Statement"* in the Javadoc? Or have you seen the limitation explicitly? ODBC explicitly doesn't limit itself to that: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/develop-app/batches-of-sql-statements?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: From the [4.3 spec](https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/jdbc-4_3-mrel3-spec/jdbc4.3-fr-spec.pdf), 13.1.2.3  Returning Unknown or Multiple Results. The example uses `cstmt.execute(sql_queries);` in plural. A string containing *queries*. I don't really think there's anything dubious about this. Think of the SQL editor use case (e.g. Dbeaver). Why shouldn't it be able to send a statement batch as a single statement to the server? Many RDBMS support this, mostly MySQL style or T-SQL style ones. It's a single `Statement` but multiple statements :)

Comment: @LukasEder All the wording in the JDBC specification and JDBC apidoc reference to executing a statement (singular), and if you read the SQL standard (which the JDBC specification implicitly "includes"), specifically section 4.39, then a statement is also singular, and there is not something that defines a collection of statements to be a (compound) statement.

Comment: @LukasEder But to be clear, that is purely from a formal, rule-lawyering point of view.

Comment: The ISO/IEC 9075-4:2016(E) 15.1 <compound statement> does require `BEGIN .. END`, but I don't see why implementations can't omit those keywords in statement batches / compound statements.

Comment: @LukasEder They can, and they do (as shown by SQL Server), but from a formal perspective it isn't "correct". And for the context of this question, executing them individually would address the desire from the OP to identify which statement was the source statement.

Comment: *"would address the desire [...]"* That's true 

Answer (score 0):

If you're in control of your SQL, you could try parsing the SQL, e.g. using [jOOQ's parser](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/sql-parser/) (disclaimer: I work for the company behind jOOQ), like this:

```java
Queries queries =
ctx.parser()
   .parse("select * from X; call sp1(); select * from Y; call sp2(); select * Z");

int count = queries.queries().length;
```

And then you'd know exactly which result set would correspond to which call. However, as you're calling stored procedures (e.g. `call sp1()`, etc.), you don't really know how many result sets will be emitted from in there.

One way to work around this limitation would be to raise warnings in between statements, e.g. if this is about SQL Server, then do something like this in between:

```sql
raiserror('statement 1', 0, 2, 3);
```

And then, [using the technique I have described here](https://blog.jooq.org/how-i-incorrectly-fetched-jdbc-resultsets-again/), you could fetch the warnings between statements to clearly delimit the individual statements:

```java
fetchLoop:
for (int i = 0, updateCount = 0; i < 256; i++) {
    boolean result = (i == 0)
        ? s.execute(sql)
        : s.getMoreResults();
 
    // Warnings here
    SQLWarning w = s.getWarnings();
    for (int j = 0; j < 255 && w != null; j++) {
        System.out.println("Warning     : " + w.getMessage());
        w = w.getNextWarning();
    }
 
    // Don't forget this
    s.clearWarnings();
 
    if (result)
        try (ResultSet rs = s.getResultSet()) {
            System.out.println("Result      :");
 
            while (rs.next())
                System.out.println("  " + rs.getString(1));
        }
    else if ((updateCount = s.getUpdateCount()) != -1)
        System.out.println("Update Count: " + updateCount);
    else
        break fetchLoop;
}
```

Again, all of this only works if you're in control of the actual SQL strings.